# "The requested operation requires elevation" message after setup

Tags: inno-setup, privileges

I created setup program for one application in inno setup , where I'm trying to run application after install, but I get this message under Windows 7 :

**The requested operation requires elevation**.

I know it's because of admin privileges. Is there a way to overcome this (except of running the setup.exe as an administrator) ?

Comment: In the sense of programming it into the executable?  The other way, is to just to set it to remember that you are an admin so it doesnt pop up. (Right clicking on properties and going that way)

Answer (score 43):

This is occurring because the executable is marked as requiring elevation.

If you try to run the application from the `[Run]` section with the `postinstall` flag, you can add the `shellexec` flag. If you do that then `Inno Setup` will start the application with the `ShellExecute` function rather than `CreateProcess`. This will make Windows bring up the UAC and run the application with elevated privileges only if needed.

Comment: Worked great. Tested with Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

Comment: This suggestion worked for me. My installer can usually run without elevation, but it needs to elevate if we need to install .NET. @martin-dimitrov's solution did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to overcome this, short of elevating yourself to administrator.

The reason this is the case is to prevent unauthorized actions from taking place on your computer.  Mostly, it allows companies to set policies on what users can and cannot do with their computers.

Answer (score 0):

I am using windows 11. What I had to do is open powershell as administrator.  This allowed me to continue.

Answer (score -3):

1. Upgrade to the latest version
2. Go to the website [ISXKB](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Vista_considerations). It will tell you aboput elevation for Vista. It will IMHO also apply for W7