# Run File One After The Other

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm trying to install a couple executable files from the run section within an inno setup file.
My File Section looks like this.

```
[Run]
#if GNTCChecked == "True"

  Filename: "{tmp}\Utilities\SDK\setup.exe"; Description: "Install Foo"; Flags: nowait postinstall shellexec

  Filename: "{tmp}\Utilities\SDK\foobar.exe"; Description: "Install Foo Update"; 
  Flags: nowait postinstall shellexec

#endif
```

The 1st file needs to be installed in order for 2nd file to install.
Basically if the first file is not installed, the 2nd will throw an error explaining that the core files are not on the system and therefore cant be installed.
At the moment, the first file is executing, and the 2nd one straight after it before the 1st one has completed installing.

Comment: Did you try removing `nowait`?  It's not going to wait for one to finish before starting the other if you explicitly tell it not to do so.

Comment: indeed i did, atm, I have removed shellexe from the 2nd one as it wasn't required, i seen this that made me use the idea.`By default, when the shellexec flag is used it will not wait until the spawned process terminates. If you need that, you must add the flag waituntilterminated. Note that it cannot and will not wait if a new process isn't spawned -- for example, if Filename specifies a folder.`

Comment: @KenWhite unfortunately no good, still acts the same as if `nowait` was there.

Comment: Did you try to remove the `shellexec` flag? Because the process will not wait due:  `By default, when processing a [Run] entry, Setup/Uninstall will wait until the program has terminated before proceeding to the next one, **unless** the nowait, **shellexec**, or waituntilidle flags are used.` !!

Comment: @moskito-x hello, I have posted the answer that allowed me to execute one file after the other and only execute once the first task was complete. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I had to do in order to execute one file after the other only when the first task had completed.

```
[Run]
#if GNTCChecked == "True"

Filename: "{tmp}\Utilities\SDK\setup.exe"; Description: "Install Foo"; 
Flags: postinstall shellexec waituntilterminated

Filename: "{tmp}\Utilities\SDK\foobar.exe"; Description: "Install Foo Update"; 
Flags: postinstall

#endif
```

Here was the information that I read that lead me to the answer.

> shellexec
>   This flag is required if Filename is not a directly executable file (an .exe or .com file). When this flag is set, Filename can be a folder or any registered file type -- including .chm, .doc, and so on. The file will be opened with the application associated with the file type on the user's system, the same way it would be if the user double-clicked the file in Explorer.
>
> By default, when the shellexec flag is used it will not wait until the spawned process terminates. If you need that, you must add the flag `waituntilterminated`. Note that it cannot and will not wait if a new process isn't spawned -- for example, if Filename specifies a folder.

Comment: Andrew, please can you explain why you need the `shellexec` flag for a `setup.exe` file?

Comment: I had it there, because if i did, an error 740 would happen, after reading this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188914/the-requested-operation-requires-elevation-message-after-setup the only way it would execute without the error was to have shellexec as a flag

Comment: So there must be a reason to run the Inno installer not with admin rights!?

Comment: mmm, thats good point, perhaps `PrivilegesRequired=admin` with the flag `runcurrentuser` or something would be better?

Comment: when i do try the above, i get error code 193, weird

Comment: Have you uninstalled what ever was installed by \Utilities\SDK\setup.exe?

Comment: Yeah, I have that in the install delete section